# RewriteRule making httpd slow

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I was added below Rule in .htaccess and it was looping.

```
RewriteRule    images/(.*) public/images/$1 [L]
```

So I changed it to this:

```
RewriteRule    ^/images/(.*) public/images/$1 [L]
```

This stopped all that excessive error logging, however even after restarting httpd we're still left with an ever growing number of httpd processes and a website which is still down.

Note:

- My All images behind in `public/images/` folder.
- I am using `http://example.com/images/abc.jpg` for displaying image into site.

Please advice for making httpd processes faster or any alternate suggestion for rewriting images.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache 2.X you need to lose the leading slash in your rule's pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) public/images/$1 [L]
```

Though I'm not sure why something like that would cause your site to slow down.